# GetItem(),ItemCount(),SubElements() functions not working in pywinauto

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, pywin32, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate tasks for teamcenter  using pywinauto python module.But I was not able to work properly with TreeViews.    When ever I'm trying to use GetItem(),SubElements(),Item() and many other function under  _treeview_element  giving error.Please look into below errors.

### I'm using python 2.7 and i also  have pywin32 module installed

```
for i in range(tr.ItemCount()):

    print tr.GetItem(i)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<pyshell#61>", line 2, in <module>

print tr.GetItem(i)   File "C:\Users\patibj\Desktop\pywinauto-

master\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1010, in GetItem
if isinstance(path[0], int):

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

---

This is when i'm trying to use GetChild()

```
a[0]  is <pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element object at 0x02EC11B0>  a[0].GetChild((1))

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>

a[0].GetChild((1))

File "C:\Users\patibj\Desktop\pywinauto- master\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 840, in GetChild

return self.Children()[index]

File "C:\Users\patibj\Desktop\pywinauto-master\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 739, in Children

if self.Item().cChildren not in (0, 1):

File "C:\Users\patibj\Desktop\pywinauto-master\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 539, in Item

return self._readitem()[0]

File "C:\Users\patibj\Desktop\pywinauto-master\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 904, in _readitem

raise ctypes.WinError() WindowsError: [Error 0] The operation completed successfully.
```

---

Please help me out .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeViewWrapper.GetItem()` method gets `path` argument which should be the string starting with back-slash `\\` symbol. Example:

```
app.Dialog.TreeView.GetItem('\\1st_level_item_name\\2ndlevelitem').Click()
```

For access by index use a list of integers:

```
app.Dialog.TreeView.GetItem([1, 0])
```

GetChild() works with explorer.exe TreeView:

```
>>> tree.GetItem([1]).GetChild(2).Text()
u'Computer'
```

Comment: Also  when i'm trying to use GetChild() function or SubElements() function  i always get error which  i mentioned above. Can you help me out with this.

Comment: Even for `<pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element object at 0x033AC430>`  when i'm trying to use  Text() function i''m getting  error of that kind.I guess problem is with `_readitem()`

Comment: Probably I need more info about your case: Windows version (Win7? Win8.1? 64-bit or 32-bit?), is your app and Python 64-bit/32-bit? Can I download your app binaries and take a look in more details?

Comment: Is your app built with Unicode character set? It's important. It seems TVM_GETITEMW returns non-null value. If you use "Multi-byte character set" in project properties it might be the case.

Comment: You may call `tr.IsUnicode()`, which value does it return?

Comment: thanks ,intially i was using 32-bit python on 64 bit os,Now i changed reinstalled 64 bit python  and it worked.

Comment: Good. It seems your question is answered. We'll add warning about mismatched 32-bit/64-bit Python and app versions.